# How to filtering out the multiple nested object in Javascript object

Tags: javascript

**Javascript**

I have a nested array of objects, I'm trying to filter the given array of objects using a property from the third level of its array property value. For example, from the below array I like to filter the entire array using the property `ListId: 10`

#### Example

```js
let test = {
   "test":true,
   "group":[
      {
         "name":"header",
         "value":[
            {
               "id":"0",
               "list":[
                  {
                     "ListId":10,
                     "name":"string1",
                     "state":"BY",
                     "techId":0
                  },
                  {
                     "ListId":11,
                     "name":"string2",
                     "state":"BY"
                  },
                  {
                     "ListId":12,
                     "name":"string3",
                     "state":"BY"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"header2",
         "value":[
            {
               "id":"01",
               "list":[
                  {
                     "ListId":100,
                     "name":"string1",
                     "state":"BY",
                     "techId":0
                  },
                  {
                     "ListId":111,
                     "name":"string2",
                     "state":"BY"
                  },
                  {
                     "ListId":121,
                     "name":"string3",
                     "state":"BY"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Filtervalue with `ListId = 10`

#### Expected output :

```json
{
   "test":true,
   "group":[
      {
         "name":"header",
         "value":[
            {
               "id":"0",
               "list":[
                  {
                     "ListId":10,
                     "name":"string1",
                     "state":"BY",
                     "techId":0
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How can I use the filter method using javascript to get this expected result?

Comment: If the objects outer shell doesn't change you can go about it like this `z.group1.value[0].list[0]` but if the structure changes, then I'm not quite sure.

Comment: So many things unclear here... By entire array, do you mean array of `z.group1.value[0].list`? Is `z.group1.value` always going to have exactly one entry everytime?

Comment: @lakshman It would be super helpful, if you could add more details here, a few helpful questions to answer would be, 1. Do you know the structure of your data, is it fixed or may change. 2. If you need a generic solution, is there a limit on data depth.

Comment: Hi, Sorry all, I just changed the expected result output for that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can two it in two times :

- First, filter the list arrays,
- Secondly filter the groups array using the `some` method

```js
let test= {
  "test": true,
  "group": [
    {
      "name": "header",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "list": [
            {
              "ListId": 10,
              "name": "string1",
              "state": "BY",
              "techId": 0
            },
            {
              "ListId": 11,
              "name": "string2",
              "state": "BY"
            },
             {
              "ListId": 12,
              "name": "string3",
              "state": "BY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "header2",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": "01",
          "list": [
            {
              "ListId": 100,
              "name": "string1",
              "state": "BY",
              "techId": 0
            },
            {
              "ListId": 111,
              "name": "string2",
              "state": "BY"
            },
             {
              "ListId": 121,
              "name": "string3",
              "state": "BY"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

test.group.forEach(group => {
  group.value.forEach(value => {
    value.list = value.list.filter(list => list.ListId === 10)
  })
})

test.group = test.group.filter(group => group.value.some(value => value.list.length > 0))

console.log(test)
```

*Note* : You should use plural names for you arrays, it helps understanding the data. For example `lists` not `list` for the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let z ={"group1": [
  {
    "name": "header",
    "value": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "list": [
          {
            "ListId": 10,
            "Name": "string1"
          },
          {
            "ListId": 11,
            "Name": "string2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]}


// This function was written from understading that 'group1' is not a fixed property, but part of a dynamic list due to the number '1'
const getItemByListId = (list, listId) => {
  const listKeys = Object.keys(list);
  const selectedListKey = listKeys.find(key => {
    const groupItems = list[key];
    const selectedItem = groupItems.find(({ value: nestedItems }) => {
      const selectedNestedItem = nestedItems.find(({ list }) => {
        const selectedList = list.find(({ ListId }) => ListId === listId)
        return selectedList;
      });
      return selectedNestedItem;
    });

    return selectedItem;
  });
  
  if (!selectedListKey) {
    return null;
  }

  return list[selectedListKey];
};


console.log(getItemByListId(z, 10));
```

Comment: Thanks @Ron for the solution, but  my expected result would be.  
{
  "group1": [
    {
      "name": "header",
      "value": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "list": [
            {
              "ListId": 10,
              "Name": "string1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}